# Calculating mean over column with condition

Tags: matlab

So my question is as follows: I have a matrix (let's take

`A = [ 1   11   22   33; 44  13   12   33; 1   14   33   44,]`

as an example) where I want to calculate the **mean** for all columns separately. The tricky part is that I only want to calculate the mean for those numbers in each column which are greater than the column 25th percentile.

I was thinking to simply create the 25th percentile and then use this as a criterion for selecting rows. This, unfortunately, does not work.

In order to further clarify: What should happen is to go through each column and calculate the 25th percentile

`prctile(A,25,1)`

And then calculating the mean only for those numbers which are respectively to their column bigger than the percentile.

Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a version of `A` which is `NaN` for values below the 25th percentile, then use the `'omitnan'` flag in `mean` to exclude those points:

```
A = [1 11 22 33; 44 13 12 33; 1 14 33 44];
B = A; % copy to leave A unaltered
B( B <= prctile(B,25,1) ) = NaN; % Turn values to NaN which we want to exclude
C = mean( B, 1, 'omitnan' ); % Omit the NaN values from the caculation
% C >>
%  [ 15.33 13.50 27.50 36.67 ]
```